# Why is the my machine decrease the stack pointer by 20 in this code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, architecture, gdb

I have the following C code compiled with GCC and disassembled to assembly in gdb. I'm using a Macbook pro with 64bit Intel i5 processor. In the 'main()' the 'char* name[2]' has 2 char pointers which should let the stack pointer decrease by 2 words(16 bytes)? However, when I disassembled in gdb it decreases by 20...Can some one help me understand?
C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{   
    char* name[2];
    name[0] = "/bin/sh";
    name[1]= NULL;
    execve(name[0],name,NULL);
}
```

gdb disassembled code:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Thu Nov  3 21:59:02 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done

(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000100000ee0 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000100000ee1 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100000ee4 <main+4>:    sub    $0x20,%rsp
0x0000000100000ee8 <main+8>:    lea    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000100000eec <main+12>:   lea    0x61(%rip),%rcx        # 0x100000f54
0x0000000100000ef3 <main+19>:   mov    %rcx,-0x18(%rbp)
0x0000000100000ef7 <main+23>:   movq   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
0x0000000100000eff <main+31>:   mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rcx
0x0000000100000f03 <main+35>:   mov    $0x0,%rdx
0x0000000100000f0d <main+45>:   mov    %rcx,%rdi
0x0000000100000f10 <main+48>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
0x0000000100000f13 <main+51>:   callq  0x100000f22 <dyld_stub_execve>
0x0000000100000f18 <main+56>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000100000f1b <main+59>:   add    $0x20,%rsp
0x0000000100000f1f <main+63>:   pop    %rbp
0x0000000100000f20 <main+64>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Don't make your life hard by dissasembling your binaries. gcc has the option `-S` which gives you the assembly directly, usually in a bit nicer form. And if you happen to have clang installed on your machine, their assembler is even better readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C allocated space size on stack for an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072236/c-allocated-space-size-on-stack-for-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, reading the assembly, name[0] is at -0x18 on the stack and name[1](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI) is at -0x10. Also, as noted before, -0x4 is used for the return value.

That leaves 12 bytes, since 0x20 is actually 32. The range -32 to -24 and the range -8 to -4.
-8 to -4 is definitely alignment, and I'm going to guess -32 to -24 is as well (for 16 byte alignment).

Edit: Note that actually 48 bytes is subtracted. The callq instruction to call into main subtracts 8 bytes from RSP, and `push %rbp` another 8.

Verified 16 byte alignment: [x86-64 System V ABI](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI) section 3.2.2 ([direct link to PDF of an old version](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that this "strange" stack frame format has everything to do with "lazy binding" calling convention that is obviously used in case of your call. I.e. you are actually calling the lazy binding stub `dyld_stub_execve`, not the `execve` itself. The result code read from `-0x4(%rbp)` after the call is probably an error code returned in case the binding was unsuccessful.

If you link the libraries statically, I guess the stack frame prepared for the call will look more conventionally.

**P.S. My answer is probably pure nonsense**, since the stack-frame-forming code is generated during compilation proper, while the decision to use static or shared library is only made at linking time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the line `<main+4>`, it's not subtracting 20 (in base 10). It's subtracting 20 in base 16, which is `16^1 * 2 + 16^0 * 0` which equals 32, or the size of 2 words.

Comment: 32 bytes is 4 words in a 64 platform. This is actually what the question is about: why 4 words instead of 2?

Comment: @AndreyT Isn't a word 2 bytes or 16 bits on all platforms?

Comment: Firstly, it depends on what you mean by "word". Typically "64-bit platform" means 64-bit word specifically. Secondly, I don't understand your logic. If you assumed that "word" is 16 bit, then 32 bytes would correspond for 16 words, not 2.

Comment: Let's just call it 2 "paragraphs", which is defined as 16 bytes, so that we can avoid the whole word size ambiguity...